# ObjC: can't subclass NSUserNotification

Tags: objective-c, subclass, nsusernotification

As the title says, I can't subclass `NSUserNotification`. Well, I can write and compile the subclass but then I can't get subclassed objects at runtime: if I create an instance of that subclass and then I test its class at runtime I always get `_NSConcreteUserNotification`. Why?

Comment: What are you doing that requires a subclass?

Comment: please explain, what you try to achieve. also show us your code you got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run into a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). They are not easily subclassed, as discussed here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html